# Proxy profiles are not supporting in the wso2 stripe extension

Tags: wso2, stripe-payments, wso2-api-manager

I have set up the WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0 publisher node.
But this particular node doesn't have internet access directly.
Therefore I have configured a proxy to allow internet access for *.stripe.com.
Then I configured the proxyProfile as below in the deployment.toml file.

```
[transport.passthru_https.sender.parameters]
proxyProfiles = "<profile><targetHosts>[api.stripe.com](http://api.stripe.com/), .*.[stripe.com](http://stripe.com/)</targetHosts><proxyHost>localhost</proxyHost><proxyPort>8080</proxyPort><proxyUserName>squidUser</proxyUserName><proxyPassword>password</proxyPassword></profile>"
```

Then tried to enable the monetization for an API and ended up with the below error.
It indicated that there is no internet access.

```
TID: [5] [api/am/publisher] [2022-02-22 15:45:14,990] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl} - Error while changing monetization status for API ID : 51a95f02-45ae-4b61-9689-5ebe510775d8 org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.MonetizationException: Unable to create product in billing engine for : FoisMstr
    at org.wso2.apim.monetization.impl.StripeMonetizationImpl.enableMonetization(StripeMonetizationImpl.java:443)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.apisApiIdMonetizePost(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:2789)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.ApisApi.apisApiIdMonetizePost(ApisApi.java:669)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.stripe.exception.ApiConnectionException: IOException during API request to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com/): [api.stripe.com](http://api.stripe.com/) Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists,you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at [support@stripe.com](mailto:support@stripe.com).
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.makeUrlConnectionRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:440)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.getStripeResponse(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:594)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.rawRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:497)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.staticRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:524)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:81)
    at com.stripe.net.ApiResource.request(ApiResource.java:190)
    at com.stripe.model.Product.create(Product.java:161)
    at org.wso2.apim.monetization.impl.StripeMonetizationImpl.enableMonetization(StripeMonetizationImpl.java:438)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: [api.stripe.com](http://api.stripe.com/)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:289)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:203)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1367)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1342)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.createPostConnection(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:251)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.makeUrlConnectionRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:412)
    ... 61 more
```

How to overcome this issue? Highly appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with this particular proxy configuration but I noticed that you are using http://api.stripe.com/ instead of https://api.stripe.com/

Can you try updating it to https://api.stripe.com/ and see if it still gives you the same error?